# Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.charts.type.PlotOrientationEnum

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My *JasperReports*'s report execute well when i preview it inside *iReport 5.1.0*. It contains a pie chart, problem comes when i need to run it from jsp file .

The error message is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.charts.type.PlotOrientationEnum
```

My env is : WIN 7 - JDK7 - NetBean 8 .

Used libraries :

- barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-digester-2.1.jar
- commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.jar
- iText-2.1.7.js2_111.jar
- jasperreports-5.1.0.jar
- jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar
- jasperreports-fonts-5.0.4.jar
- jcommon-1.0.15.jar
- jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
- ojdbc6.jar
- spring.jar

Here is a full error message :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation
    at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.type.PlotOrientationEnum.<clinit>(PlotOrientationEnum.java:42)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseChartPlot.<init>(JRBaseChartPlot.java:76)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.base.JRBasePiePlot.<init>(JRBasePiePlot.java:71)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.design.JRDesignPiePlot.<init>(JRDesignPiePlot.java:52)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignChart.setChartType(JRDesignChart.java:744)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignChart.<init>(JRDesignChart.java:189)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.xml.JRPieChartFactory.createObject(JRPieChartFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.FactoryCreateRule.begin(FactoryCreateRule.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1583)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:749)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:846)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:775)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:628)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:243)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:230)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:218)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:172)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:171)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:448)
    at logic.PDFReport.printReport(PDFReport.java:93)
    at org.apache.jsp.Reports_jsp._jspService(Reports_jsp.java:178)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: are these files copied inside WEB-INF/lib as well?

Comment: not exactly yes , cause i call the jasper report from java object method , and the jsp just call this method , however yes it copied to D:\myproject\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\mypackage\myjars .

Comment: @Mohammedashraf You should post the full stacktrace

Comment: ok i changed my question to include the full error message dear "Alex K"

Answer (score 0):

download and add this lib. in your project.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/novatec/testit/livingdoc-confluence5-plugin/1.1.2/livingdoc-confluence5-plugin-1.1.2.jar

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer to explain why adding this library will solve the problem, rather than just providing a link

Comment: If you're using a dependency manager (Maven, SBT, Ivy, Gradle, etc.) add this lib into your project file. If you're using a dependency manager, that's all there is to resolving this exception